# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. Not getting What declaration mistake I have made

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract funcction{
    
    unit age = 18;

    function changeAge(unit _x) public view returns(unit){
        return _x+1;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

you misspelled uint

its `uint` not `unit`

**fun fact!**
`uint` defaults to `uint256`